# How to display an image from a server side store in memory?

Tags: c#, image-processing, asp.net-mvc-4

I have images saved in a server side folder. The server has the path of the images. The client cannot access that folder but the server can. I cannot attach the URL in the src attribute in an img tag because the browser will not be able to display as the client does not have permission.

How can I display those images in this case? I was told that the server can save the image in memory and then render those images in the client side - how can I do that?  I'm using MVC 4, c# with sql server 2008 r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store images in a folder then you can use `File()` method with physical file path directly:

```
public ActionResult Image(string id)
{
    var dir = Server.MapPath("/Images");
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, id + ".jpg");
    return base.File(path, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Comment: if the image is tif, which would be the type?? image/tif?

Comment: Yes, you should use "image/tiff" (double "f") in this case. You can find other image content types here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_image

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `File` overload that takes a path and a mime type.  In your controller action:

```
// Sub the appropriate mime type for the image
return File(thePathFromTheDb, "image/jpg");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492492(v=vs.108).aspx

Alternately if your image data were coming from the DB, in your controller action:

```
byte[] bytes = GetImageBytesFromDatabase();  // Sub your code to get bytes
return File(bytes, "image/jpg"); // Sub the appropriate mime type for the image
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460208(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: How does the server know where to find the file? Remember that the image is in a folder, not save in the database.

Comment: Hmmm my bad, thought image data was coming from the DB.  Updating shortly.

Comment: So, once a get the file path, ther server will return me the image?

Comment: Yes, if you appropriately map it with Server.MapPath.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the images to point to a controller. The controller then needs to return a `FileResult` with the correct mimetype to the browser.

The sequence is as follows:

1. Browser requests page
2. Server return page with back link (e.g. `<img src='/files/get/123.png'/>`)
3. Browser requests image in back link
4. Server reads image from <del>disk</del> DB answering to controller (`FilesController`) action call (`Get`) with a `FileResult` return type. Remember to set the mime type to `image\png` or `gif` or `jpeg` based on your image format.
5. Server returns image to brower